# Smog test fail, lack of oil?

Tags: toyota, corolla, emissions, p0300, p0301

I have a 2001 Toyota Corolla.

It failed a smog test and it misfires. It has a code that the vehicle repair shop doesn't recognize, could this be because of lack of oil in my car? My stepson has never checked the oil and unfortunately I recently found out. Is it too late for my car. The codes are: P0300, P0301, P1349.

Answer (score 3):

**Here are some of the translations for your errors by code**

- P0300 - This random multiple misfires on random cylinders
- P0301 - Cylinder 1 misfire.  You could have a bad spark plug, a bad spark plug wire, a bad coil for cylinder 1, a bad wire to the coil for cylinder 1, an open in your wire harness for cylinder 1. In conjunction with your above error I would flow to the idea of an air leak or vacuum leak that is leading to the misfires.
- P1349 - Low or dirty engine oil, incorrect valve timig, faulty oil control valve, a faulty variable vale timing control assembly or a faulty ECM.  This can be tricky to troubleshoot as there are a wide variety of possible issues associated with this.  Changing the oil is cheap and necessary.  It would be a good idea to start there.

If you have follow up questions, please feel free to ask another question.  Best of luck.